# Dealing with missing values for categorical variables

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I am currently working on the dataset [HR Analytics: Job Change of Data Scientists](https://www.kaggle.com/code/joshuaswords/awesome-hr-data-visualization-prediction/data) in Kaggle. The dataset is about a company wanting to know which of the candidates that took part in their training intends to work for the company or look for a new job. Information related to the candidates' demographics, education, and experience is collected.

There are plenty of missing values in the dataset for the categorical variables (Most of the categorical variables have less than 10% missing values, and only a minority have more than 25% missing values). The first thing that comes to mind is a complete case analysis, but there are too many missing values, and simply removing them might not be the best idea.

I consider categorising missing values as another category, like "Not provided" or "prefer not to say", or multiple imputations. Still, I am not sure if these are the best approaches.

So how do I deal with these missing values? I researched this matter, but I was overwhelmed when I found out there are many ways to deal with missing values (I'm relatively new to statistical learning). I am looking for advice, particularly on this dataset, what's the best way to deal with the missing values.

Comment: This is indeed a hard question. Dropping these rows only works if the data is MCAR, if not then there might be biases. Imputing them with some new category, "missing", is a valid approach, you might find some pattern in these rows... but maybe not.

Comment: @user2974951 So to my understanding, if the data is MCAR, I can perform a complete case analysis, but if it's MAR, then imputation is a better way to deal with the missing values, correct?

Comment: Yes, if your data is MAR you should probably not just drop the missing values, otherwise you might get biased estimates. In that case how you impute the missing values is also very important and can yield very different results. But your approach of coding all the missing values as some other category is one such potential approach.

Comment: And is using different imputations on a single dataset a valid approach? For example, I replace the missing value in variable 1 with a new category, while for variable 2 I replace it with an existing value?

Comment: Your question is very broad: How to deal with lots of missing data? There are lots of options! See for example [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/). It's rarely a good idea is to remove data because it's inconvenient to model; in your case because there are missing values.